# Where on earth is the wiki?

Tags: documentation

I had dozens of informtive links bookmarked.. Now they're all gone.

For example
https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Now all it does is forward me to the main page the new 'documentation', which has none of these things..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you will have to use google cache to see your bookmarks and maybe make a copy of them.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:krjnLyLeA6cJ:www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de

I can not tell you if the wiki will return. I am glad the magento forum is finally back after 9 months downtime.